# What happen if there's no one mining bitcoin?

Tags: mining-theory

I read that miner are in a way contributed to the transaction progress of bitcoin. So, that means if there's no one mining anymore, the bitcoin can no longer be transacted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true, that's exactly what would happen.

However the rewards for mining would increase proportionally so if there was any value in bitcoins at all then someone would be motivated to start mining to gather the rewards. That's why this won't happen, if 90% of people stopped mining then the rewards for mining would be 10 times higher.

Plus there are enough businesses involved financially in bitcoin now that I would expect them to invest in some mining capacity to keep the network going.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, yes, this is true.

Answer (score 1):

If no-one mines a Bitcoin like crypto-currency it will stop to work, this mean that transaction can be created and shared on the network but that they are not confirmed anymore and that there will not be any new money supply.  This don't mean that the crypto-currency is 'dead', Bitcoin like crypto-currency will not die until someone owns it's block chain.

Note that this is what happened to an alt-coin called 'junkcoin'.
People had to mine blocks themselves to get their coins on exchanges.